# naming melted iteratively mapped lists in the tidyverse

Tags: r, reshape2, purrr, tidyverse

I often do loops inside of loops and then in the end melt the lists to a dataframe for graphing.

```
ac<-list("BB","AA")
ca<-list(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(6,5,4))
cc<-map(a,function(y) map(ca,~paste0(.x,y)))
reshape2::melt(cc)
```

Q1:Is there another way of doing maps inside of maps without resorting to `function(y)`

However, since my lists often are unnamed I tend to add the values of the list as name as follows:

```
map_test<-function(list_in,...){
  if (is.null(names(list_in))){
    names(list_in)<-list_in
    }
  map(list_in,...)
}
cc2=map_test(ac,function(y) map_test(ca,~paste0(.x,y)))
df=reshape2::melt(cc2)
```

The resulting df has names L2 and L1 and I´d prefer if the names were ca and ac respectively.

```
nam.cons<-NULL
map_test2<-function(list_in,...){
  nam.cons<<-c(nam.cons,deparse(substitute(list_in)))

  if (is.null(names(list_in))){
    names(list_in)<-list_in
  }
  map(list_in,...)
}

cc3=map_test2(ac,function(y) map_test2(ca,~paste0(.x,y)))
cc4<-reshape2::melt(cc3)
names(cc4)<-c("value",rev(unique(nam.cons)))
```

Now this can get messy very quick if I forget to reset the `nam.cons` variable. I could create 1,2,3,4..n versions of this in separate functions, but

Q2: Is it possible to create **one** melt_map function that would allow both to accept looping over n-different lists and that in the end also keep the n-different list names as column-names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to loop through every combination of list items, elegantly, and without losing our list names.

So let's build all the combinations and store the names already :

```
library(tidyverse)               # data
ac<-list("BB","AA")              #
ca<-list(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(6,5,4))  #

df <- merge(tibble(ac),tibble(ca)) 

#   ac      ca
# 1 BB 1, 2, 3
# 2 AA 1, 2, 3
# 3 BB 6, 5, 4
# 4 AA 6, 5, 4
```

Then we're ready to play and do what we want painlessly in the tidy way, without double uses of maps and substitute calls, for example:

```
df %>%
  mutate(ac=unlist(ac),
         name =names(ca)) %>%
  unnest %>%
  mutate(value = paste0(ca,ac))

#    ac name ca value
# 1  BB    a  1   1BB
# 2  BB    a  2   2BB
# 3  BB    a  3   3BB
# 4  AA    a  1   1AA
# 5  AA    a  2   2AA
# 6  AA    a  3   3AA
# 7  BB    b  6   6BB
# 8  BB    b  5   5BB
# 9  BB    b  4   4BB
# 10 AA    b  6   6AA
# 11 AA    b  5   5AA
# 12 AA    b  4   4AA
```